# Roll up rows only if data matches or one is NULL in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to merge the tables only if all the columns match, or if non matching columns are due to NULLs

For example, if I want to join table `t1` that looks like this:

```
 id | column1 | column2 | column3
----+---------+---------+---------
  A |  NULL   |    1    |   NULL
  B |  NULL   |    3    |    v5
  C |   v6    |   NULL  |   NULL
```

To table `t2` that looks like this:

```
 id | column1 | column2 | column3
----+---------+---------+---------
  A |   v1    |    1    |    v2   
  A |  NULL   |    2    |    v3
  B |   v4    |   NULL  |   NULL
  C |   v7    |    4    |    v8
```

I would like the resulting target table to be:

```
 id | column1 | column2 | column3
----+---------+---------+---------
  A |   v1    |    1    |    v2   
  A |  NULL   |    2    |    v3
  B |   v4    |    3    |    v5
  C |   v6    |   NULL  |   NULL
  C |   v7    |    4    |    v8
```

Where row1 in `t1` and row1 in `t2` are *merged*, and row2 in `t1` and row3 in `t2` are merged, while retaining other rows in `t1` and `t2` without a match.

Would this be somehow achievable through COALESCE and FULL JOINs or any other methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . .  . If I understand correctly, you want to treat `NULL` as a wildcard when you do the `JOIN`.  So, `NULL` in either table would match any value in the other table.

If so, then a `FULL JOIN` on all columns (with the right logic) should do what you want:

```
select t1.id,
       coalesce(t2.col1, t1.col1) as col1,
       coalesce(t2.col2, t1.col2) as col2,
       coalesce(t2.col3, t1.col3) as col3
from t1 full join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and
        (t1.col1 = t2.col1 or t1.col1 is null or t2.col1 is null) and
        (t1.col2 = t2.col2 or t1.col2 is null or t2.col2 is null) and
        (t1.col3 = t2.col3 or t1.col4 is null or t2.col3 is null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with full outer join and COALESCE

```
select table1.id,COALESCE(table1.column1, table2.column1) as column1,
COALESCE(table1.column2, table2.column2) as column2,
COALESCE(table1.column3, table2.column3) as column3 from table1 
full outer join table2 on table1.id=table2.id
```